# How can I combine this 2 cells into one?

Tags: html

I'm trying to combine the cells G and H into one, let's see my code for the follow table:

[image]

```
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="5">A</td>
                <td colspan="3">B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">C</td>
                <td rowspan="4">D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">E</td>
                <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>G</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>H</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I do? I try to do <td rowspan="2">G</td> but it doesn't work.

What I want is:

[image]

Is there a way to make that table I want, using only HTML?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see? What you have tried is what I would expect from merging those 2 cell.

Comment: I want what is shown in the second image, the code that I place is the one that gives me the first image.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.... I read that as this is what I get. Time for more coffee

Comment: Is there a way to make that table I want, using only HTML?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="5" height="100">A</td>
                <td colspan="3" height="20">B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" height="20">C</td>
                <td rowspan="4" colspan="1" height="80">D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" height="60">E</td>
                <td height="20">F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="40">G</td>
          </tr>      
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hi Jean. I don't think you can do this with plain HTML, since you're using 5 rowspan and have only 4 rows. However, you can style it with simple CSS, I'm adding code snippet for example

Comment: In my code I have 5 rows not  4,  but I don't know how to merge the two cells G and H into one...

Comment: @JEANLEONARDO, but once you merge G&H you no longer have 5 rows , but 4 as the H cell is the only effective cell in row 5. What you really want is the G cell to have double height. This answer demonstrates one way to achieve that. With more dynamic content, it gets trickier.

Comment: It's important to note that the height attribute is deprecated. CSS should be used instead.

Comment: Is there a way to make that table I want, using only HTML? Without deprecated attributes?

Comment: Why just HTML? The only reason I can see for that is HTML email. In which case you should be using style attributes instead.